# How to save data in previous frame in Flash

Tags: actionscript-3

I have some movieclips called one, two, three, four, five that appear on stage with addChild. I also have 4 editable text fields on stage called theText1, theText2, theText3 and theText4 where users must write the numbers 4, 1, 5, 2 in each one. If they write something wrong they are sent in a next frame where they take some feedback and come back in current frame to correct their answer. The problem is that when they come back all are "reset". Movie clips added before and numbers written before **must be** on stage. How can i do that? (I need something simple because i am new to flash and as3).

Answer (score 0):

Because MovieClips don't store frame states.
You should store values, and restore them, after returning to the frame.

```
//Add these 2 helper functions in your frame with Quiz UI

function restoreValues():void{
    if(this.storedValues != null){
        //Restore data
        theText1.text = this.storedValues.txt1;           
    }
}

function storeValues():void{
    //Save as much data as you want
    this.storedValues = {
        txt1 : theText1.text
    };
}
```

When you go to the another frame, call `storeValues` right before you change frame and store all necessary data in simple object.

```
checkQuizButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onCheck);

function onCheck(e: MouseEvent):void{
    storeValues();
    nextFrame();
}
```

In the frame with Quiz ui components, just after initialisation of all ui components, call `restoreValues();` Don't forget to change functions for your needs.

Comment: i need some more help:   When you go to the another frame, call storeValues right before you change frame and store all necessary data in simple object   -  How i call storeValues?   what do you mean by saying change functions?

Comment: I have added example, by "changing" I mean, that It's only example, by analogy for one field, you could add as many fields as you want...

Comment: i get this error TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
 at _fla::MainTimeline/storeValues()

Comment: Check if fields that you access in `storeValues` are defined.